# Python: schedule script to run inside IDE

Tags: python, automation, ide, scheduled-tasks, spyder

I have a python script that I have to run from windows using an IDE (Spyder) on a regular basis.  Using task scheduler, I can successfully run the script outside of the IDE, and separately, I can successfully open the script inside Spyder.  However I have not been able to open the script in Spyder and then run it in the IDE.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why does the script *needs* to be executed within the IDE? IDE stands for **I**ntegrated **D** *evelopment* *E*nvironment.

Comment: The end user wants to see the results without storing them elsewhere, among other reasons.

Comment: You can print the results to the screen. I doubt what you are asking for is possible.

Comment: You could probably achieve what you want by using [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to open Spyder, open your script on it by using `Ctrl+O` and then sending **F5** to its window to tell Spyder to run that script.

Comment: @DeepSpace I'd be surprised if that's true.  It's certainly possible for other programs like Matlab and R.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba  This looks like an interesting program.  I'll look into it.  That said, surely there exists a more direct way with task scheduler.